# Which Smalltalk object should be passed to a C function expecting const char*

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I want to call the following C function:
`int ssh_userauth_password (ssh_session session, const char * username, const char * password)`

But regular Smalltalk strings are not working:
`library ssh_login: session userAuth: nil password: 'myPwd'.`

`session` is a pointer that i already have and works ok.
But `const char *` are not mapped to normal string.
Is there any class to map this ?
Also i tried with CPointer and asByteArray but both fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a CPointer object. Easiest way to do that is via `'yay' gcCopyCStringToHeap`. Alternatively there‘re variations like `gcCopyUnicodeStringToHeap`.

Comment: It seems i have another problem because is not working with gcCopyToHeapEncoding nor with copyToHeapUnicode.

Comment: what problem do you have? you should receive a handle, two handles actually, which you both pass to the C function.

Comment: The call should answer 0 (SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) but answer -1 (SSH_AUTH_ERROR: A serious error happened). So my question has been answer because i can pass a Smalltalk string as argument to a C function. But my problem remains. The error is ('Writing packet: error on socket (or connection closed): Unknown error')

Comment: If  you have access to the receiving end, try to increase the loglevel for sshd in order to find out what the issue is. Can be anything from encoding over protocol issues over encryption and so on.